# Extracting 5 words before and after an specific word

Tags: r

How can I extract the words/sentence next to an specific word? Example:

"On June 28, Jane went to the cinema and ate popcorn"

I would like to choose 'Jane' and get [-2,2], meaning:

"June 28, Jane went to"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could make a function to help out. This might make it a little more dynamic.

```
library(tidyverse)

txt <- "On June 28, Jane went to the cinema and ate popcorn"

grab_text <- function(text, target, before, after){
  min <- which(unlist(map(str_split(text, "\\s"), ~grepl(target, .x))))-before
  max <- which(unlist(map(str_split(text, "\\s"), ~grepl(target, .x))))+after

  paste(str_split(text, "\\s")[[1]][min:max], collapse = " ")
}

grab_text(text = txt, target = "Jane", before = 2, after  = 2)
#> [1] "June 28, Jane went to"
```

First we split the sentence, then we figure out the position of the target, then we grab any word before or after (number specified in the function), last we collapse the sentence back together.

Comment: Great work! All the answers were good, but this is the one that works better on the long run. Would it capture more words if the search word repeats in the same sentence? Is there a way to obtain only the words and not the sentence?

Comment: If you're really planning on using this, you need a lot more validation. This will error out on multiple occurrences or if the before or after is too large (e.g., if Jane is the first word in the sentence and before is anything but 0).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any suggestions on how to solve the starting name problem?

Comment: Sure, that is pretty easy to take care of. What exactly do you want it to do if it starts with the name? only extract words after?

Answer (score 4):

I have a shorter version using `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
txt <- "On June 28, Jane went to the cinema and ate popcorn"
str_extract(txt,"([^\\s]+\\s+){2}Jane(\\s+[^\\s]+){2}")

[1] "June 28, Jane went to"
```

The function `str_extract` extract the patern form the string. The regex `\\s` is for white space, and `[^\\s]` is the negation of it, so anything but white space. So the whole pattern is `Jane` with twice a white space before and after and something composed by anything but whitespace

The advantage is that it is already vectorized, and if you have a vector of text you can use `str_extract_all`:

```
s <- c("On June 28, Jane went to the cinema and ate popcorn. 
          The next day, Jane hiked on a trail.",
       "an indeed Jane loved it a lot")

str_extract_all(s,"([^\\s]+\\s+){2}Jane(\\s+[^\\s]+){2}")

[[1]]
[1] "June 28, Jane went to"   "next day, Jane hiked on"

[[2]]
[1] "an indeed Jane loved it"
```

Comment: Is there a way to only get the words? No need for comma or anything but simple words in order to count them later on.

Comment: you can get word by using `\\w` in regex. `str_extract(txt,"\\w")` will extract all words

Comment: It returns NA when i try: 
str_extract_all(s,"([^\\w]+\\w+){2}Jane(\\w+[^\\w]+){2}")

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with an expansion for multiple occurrences. Basically, split on whitespace, find the word, expand the indices, then make a list of results.

```r
s <- "On June 28, Jane went to the cinema and ate popcorn. The next day, Jane hiked on a trail."
words <- strsplit(s, '\\s+')[[1]]
inds <- grep('Jane', words)
lapply(inds, FUN = function(i) {
  paste(words[max(1, i-2):min(length(words), i+2)], collapse = ' ')
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "June 28, Jane went to"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "next day, Jane hiked on"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
stringr::str_extract(text, "(?:[^\\s]+\\s){5}Jane(?:\\s[^\\s]+){5}")
```